# How to use getUpdatedSchedulerEvent in the scheduler of alloyui

Tags: javascript, frontend, alloy-ui

I'm new of alloyui. I'm currently using alloyui for defining a simple scheduler view. When I'm reading the alloyui's [api doc](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerEventRecorder.html#method_on), I'm very confused about how to use the function getUpdatedSchedulerEvent. I searched it on the google, but the examples are hard to find and the documents don't explain it very straightforward as well.

Can someone provide some detailed explanation or simple examples to me?

Thank you very much.

The code of defining the scheduler I used is below:

```
var schedulerViews = [
    new Y.SchedulerWeekView(),
    new Y.SchedulerDayView(),
    new Y.SchedulerMonthView()
];

var eventRecord = new Y.SchedulerEventRecorder({
    on: {
        save: function (event) {
            var start_time = this.getClearStartDate();
            var end_time = this.getClearEndDate();
            var facility_name = "{{ item.facility.facility_name }}";
            $.ajax({
                url: "/TT/#tab-{{item.facility.facility_name}}",
                type: 'post',
                data: {json_data: JSON.stringify({start_time: start_time, end_time: end_time, facility_name: facility_name})},
                success: function (response) {
                },
                complete: function () {

                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                    alert("error doing something");
                }
            });

{#                                    alert('Save Event:' + this.isNew() + ' --- ' + this.getContentNode().val());#}
            alert('Save Event:' + this.isNew() + ' --- ' + this.getClearStartDate());

        },
        edit: function (event) {
            alert('Edit Event:' + this.isNew() + ' --- ' + this.getContentNode().val());
        },
        delete: function (event) {
            alert('Delete Event:' + this.isNew() + ' --- ' + this.getContentNode().val());
        }
    }
});

new Y.Scheduler({
    boundingBox: '#myScheduler-{{item.facility.facility_name}}',
    items: events,
    render: true,
    views: schedulerViews,
    activeView: schedulerViews[0],
    eventRecorder: eventRecord
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had luck doing the following:

`data: { "content": this.getContentNode().val(), "startDate": new Date( this.get('startDate') ).getTime() / 1000 - 18000, "endDate": new Date( this.get('endDate') ).getTime() / 1000 -18000 },`